# Display other inputs based on the value of another input using Laravel and AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, forms

I'm a beginner in Laravel and I'm trying to create a form and submit it to the database.

I managed to save the data to the database using the following code.

My blade:

```
    <form id="castingform" method="post" action="castingss"   enctype="multipart/form-data">
           
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <input type="hidden" id="id_hidden" name="id" />
        <div class="form-row">
           <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label for="casting_name">Nom</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="casting_name" name="casting_name" placeholder="Nom" >
              <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('casting_name') }}</span>
           </div>
           <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label for="casting_cin">CIN</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="casting_cin" name="casting_cin" placeholder="Cin">
              <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('casting_cin') }}</span>
           </div>
           </div>
         <div class="form-row">
           <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label for="casting_email">Email</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="casting_email" name="casting_email"  placeholder="Email">
              <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('casting_email') }}</span>
           </div>
           <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label for="casting_phone">Téléphone</label>
              <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="casting_phone" name="casting_phone" placeholder="Téléphone">
              <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('casting_phone') }}</span>
           </div>
         </div>
         <div class="form-row">
           <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label for="casting_age">Age</label>
              <input type="number" class="form-control" id="casting_age" name="casting_age" placeholder="Age">
              <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('casting_age') }}</span>
           </div>
           <div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label for="casting_sexe">Sexe</label>
              <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                <input type="radio"  name="casting_sexe"  id="casting_sexeh" class="custom-control-input" value="homme">
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="casting_sexeh">Homme</label>
              </div>
              <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                  <input type="radio"  name="casting_sexe" id="casting_sexef" class="custom-control-input"  value="femme">
                  <label class="custom-control-label" for="casting_sexef" >Femme</label>
              </div>
           </div>
         </div>        
         <div class="form-row">
           <div class="form-group col-md-6">
             <label for="casting_city">City</label>
             <input type="text" class="form-control" name="casting_city" id="casting_city">
             <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('casting_city') }}</span>
           </div>
           <div class="form-group col-md-6">
             <label for="casting_address">Address 2</label>
             <input type="text" class="form-control" id="casting_address" name="casting_address" >
             <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('casting_address') }}</span>  
           </div>
         </div>
         <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
               <span class="input-group-text">Upload</span>
            </div>
            <div class="custom-file">
               <input type="file" name="casting_photo" class="custom-file-input" id="casting_photo">
               <label class="custom-file-label" for="casting_photo">Choose file</label>
            </div>
         </div>
        <div class=" col-md-6">
          <span id="store_image" text-align: center></span>
        </div>
         </br> </br>  </br>  </br>   </br>
         <span class="result"></span>
        <div class="form-group" align="center">
          <input type="hidden" name="action" id="action" />
          <input type="hidden" name="hidden_id" id="hidden_id" />
          <input type="submit" name="action_button" id="action_button" class="btn btn-warning" value="ADD" />
        </div>
        <div class=" col-md-6">
          <span id="form_result"></span>
        </div>
     </form>
<!--------------------- script---------------------
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#castingform').on('submit', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  if($('#action').val() == 'Add')
  {
   $.ajax({
    url:"{{ route('castingss.store') }}",
    method:"POST",
    data: new FormData(this),
    dataSrc: "",
    contentType: false,
    cache:false,
    processData: false,
    dataType:"json",
    success:function(data)
    {
     var html = '';
     if(data.errors)
     {
      html = '<div class="alert alert-danger">';
      for(var count = 0; count < data.errors.length; count++)
      {
       html += '<p>' + data.errors[count] + '</p>';
      }
      html += '</div>';
     }
     if(data.success)
     {
      alert('je suis là');
      html = '<div class="alert alert-success">' + data.success + '</div>';
      $('#sample_form')[0].reset();
      $('#datatableRows').DataTable().ajax.reload();
     }
     $('#form_result').html(html);
    }
   })
  }
});
});
</script>
```

My controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)

{
      $rules = array(

         'casting_name' => 'required',
         'casting_cin' => 'required|max:8|unique:castings',
         'casting_email' => 'required|email|unique:castings',
         'casting_phone' => 'required',
         'casting_age' => 'required',
         'casting_sexe' => 'required',
         'casting_city' => 'required',
         'casting_address' => 'required',
         'casting_photo' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048'
            
             );

                    $error = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);

                    if($error->fails())
                    {
                        return response()->json(['errors' => $error->errors()->all()]);
                    }

                    $image = $request->file('casting_photo');

                    $new_name = rand() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();

                    $image->move(public_path('castingimages'), $new_name);

                    $form_data = array(
                        'casting_name'        =>  $request->casting_name,
                        'casting_cin'         =>  $request->casting_cin,
                         'casting_email'        =>  $request->casting_email,
                        'casting_phone'         =>  $request->casting_phone,
                         'casting_age'        =>  $request->casting_age,
                        'casting_sexe'         =>  $request->casting_sexe,
                         'casting_city'        =>  $request->casting_city,
                        'casting_address'         =>  $request->casting_address,
                        'casting_photo'             =>  $new_name
                    );

                    Casting::create($form_data);

                    return response()->json(['success' => 'Data Added successfully.']);      
    }
```

All works very well for me, but now I wanted to add something else to my form.
I wanted based on the value of the input age to display other inputs.
This means if the age is less than 18, two other inputs, one for the name of the guarantor and the other for the identification number of the guarantor, had to be displayed and the age was recorded in the database with the name and the identifier of the guarantor and if the age is over 18 years old we do nothing we record the data in the database with the age of 18 years old.

How could I do this? If you have an idea please give me the lead to follow to achieve this.

**EDIT**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#castingform').on('submit', function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
 var castingAgeInput = document.getElementById('casting_age');
var guarantorContainer = document.querySelector('.js-guarantor-container');
var guarantorIdentificationNumberContainer = document.querySelector('.js-guarantor_identification_number-container');

castingAgeInput.addEventListener('change', function(evt) {
    if (+evt.target.value < 18) {
      guarantorContainer.removeAttribute('hidden');
      guarantorIdentificationNumberContainer.removeAttribute('hidden');
    } else {
      guarantorContainer.setAttribute('hidden', true);
      guarantorIdentificationNumberContainer.setAttribute('hidden', true);
    }
      if($('#action').val() == 'Add')
      {
       $.ajax({
        url:"{{ route('castingss.store') }}",
        method:"POST",
        data: new FormData(this),
        dataSrc: "",
        contentType: false,
        cache:false,
        processData: false,
        dataType:"json",
        success:function(data)
        {
         var html = '';
         if(data.errors)
         {
          html = '<div class="alert alert-danger">';
          for(var count = 0; count < data.errors.length; count++)
          {
           html += '<p>' + data.errors[count] + '</p>';
          }
          html += '</div>';
         }
         if(data.success)
         {
          alert('je suis là');
          html = '<div class="alert alert-success">' + data.success + '</div>';
          $('#sample_form')[0].reset();
          $('#datatableRows').DataTable().ajax.reload();
         }
         $('#form_result').html(html);
        }
       })
      }
    });
    });
    </script>
```

But it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add these fields `hidden` and toggle their visibility:

```js
var castingAgeInput = document.getElementById('casting_age');
var guarantorContainer = document.querySelector('.js-guarantor-container');
var guarantorIdentificationNumberContainer = document.querySelector('.js-guarantor_identification_number-container');

castingAgeInput.addEventListener('change', function(evt) {
    if (+evt.target.value < 18) {
      guarantorContainer.removeAttribute('hidden');
      guarantorIdentificationNumberContainer.removeAttribute('hidden');
    } else {
      guarantorContainer.setAttribute('hidden', true);
      guarantorIdentificationNumberContainer.setAttribute('hidden', true);
    }
});
```

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="casting_age">Age</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="casting_age" name="casting_age" placeholder="Age">
    <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('casting_age') }}</span>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-6 js-guarantor-container" hidden>
    <label for="guarantor">Guarantor</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="guarantor" name="guarantor" placeholder="Guarantor">
    <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('guarantor') }}</span>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-6 js-guarantor_identification_number-container" hidden>
    <label for="guarantor_identification_number">Guarantor identification number</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="guarantor_identification_number" name="guarantor_identification_number" placeholder="Age">
    <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('guarantor_identification_number') }}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I have just a question what I have to do inside my Controller?

Comment: You also have to add the HTML to the blade view. Nothing in the Controller has to be changed.

Comment: It works for me thank you , but I should stock in database name and the id of the guarantor if the age is greater than 18

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get that.